# Promoting my GitHub repo

Tags: github, open-source, uwp

I've just recently open-sourced my app, but I'm not entirely sure how to promote the GitHub repository. The whole idea of open-sourcing it was to get the power of the developer community on my side, but I'm not sure how to get people noticing the repo. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl Fogel's [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/) has a chapter on this. It includes posting on relevant mailing lists, having a good project page, and a communication infrastructure (e.g., mailing list).

Comment: The question is off-topic. This isn't the place to be promoting 3rd-party books.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Fair enough, but why don't you post the "off topic" complaint on the question instead?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Care to explain why I cannot refer to books? Or does it matter whether it's a classic like the GoF Design Patterns vs some random book?

Comment: I already voted to close the question as off-topic. And with the question nearly closed at this point, the OP will soon fully understand why the question is closed, as the close reason will be posted. You had already posted an answer here, so I posted my comment under your answer (in addition to close-voting).. Regarding book-posting: It's an offsite resource for a problem unrelated to programming (as defined by StackOverflow).